# {keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format }Need to generate SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint

Tags: java, android, react-native, ssl, keystore

This is the error that is coming up while generating the SHA-1 fingerprint, I wrote my entire code on VS Code. I used JDK 1.7.0_80 for keytool and generated JKS file from Android Studio.
This is the command I used `{keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\devup\ReactNativeMap1\test.jks -alias test}`
Then I had to enter the keystore password, which I am sure I wrote correctly.
After typing the password, this is the error that showed up.

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Unknown Source)   
at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

I tried matching the keytool and java versions but didn't work.
I tried using JRE 1.8.0_251 but didn't work.
I tried older versions of JRE but got the same error.
How can I solve this error.

[Here is the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mutwe.png)

Comment: Try setting the keystore type to PKCS11.